How to get the fulfillment status history in SF OMS
I am joining OrderItemSummary and FulfillmentOrderLineItem to get the current status and fulfillment quantity as following.
How do I get the history of the Status as it changed from Ordered > Allocated / Cancelled > Fulfilled?
select    
  order_item_summary.status  
  , order_item_summary.description  
  , order_item_summary.reserved_at_location_id  
  , fulfillment_order_line_item.quantity  
  , fulfillment_order_line_item.original_quantity
from order_item_summary
left join fulfillment_order_line_item 
  on order_item_summary.id = fulfillment_order_line_item.order_item_summary_id 
where order_item_summary.order_summary_id = 'nnn';


Unfortunately Field History Tracking is not available on Order Summary, Order Product Summary and Fulfillment Objects. You can vote on the idea here
A workaround to see the history of a field, is to activate Feed History on that relevant field. This can be done for the Status field on the Order Product Summary Object as well as the Fulfillment Object.
If the requirement is to report on the changes, then it might be difficult to create a report on the Feed History entries, which might require you then to build out some sort of custom solution that you can also report on (such as a custom object that has records created when the Status field changes, basically a custom built field history tracking tool).
Good luck!

Thanks Adriaan. So currently there is no way to figure out when a Fulfilled Order was moved from Ordered to Allocated Status?

Not from anything other than the options I mentioned. There are endless custom built options that you can use, but I haven't come across anything OOTB other than the Feed tab on the Order Summary showing when a Fulfillment Order Status changes (I did not set this up, just saw it reporting the changes)

Got it. I will start ingesting this data into the Data Warehouse, so that we can report on it.

Good luck! It is unfortunate. Hopefully they implement the idea quickly. Do you mind marking my answer as the preferred one if it has helped you?
